# Grouping collection with threshold filtering

Tags: mapreduce

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm to do the following in a map reduce. I receive a bunch of objects and the user ids of the owner. In other words, I receive a bunch of pairs:

```
(object, uid)
```

I want to end up with a list of pairs `(object,count)`, where `count` refers to the number of times the object occurs in the list. The caveat is that we would need to filter everything as follows:

1. We should only include object pairs such that the object is repeated for at least `n` different uids.
2. We should only include objects such that the total count of times it repeats is at least m.

Objects and users are all represented as integers. The problem is that it would be trivial to convert each `(object,uid)` pair into `(object, 1)` and then reduce together these by summing the second integers. I could then filter everything that doesn't hit the threshold of (2). However, at this point I would have lost the information necessary to filter by (1), which is what I don't know how to incorporate into this. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most natural way is to run two MR jobs in sequence. Goal of the first job is to count how much times each `object` is owned by each `uid`. Result is triplets (`object`, `uid`, `count`). `uid` field here is for debugging purpose only -- it is not required in second job. Second job groups triplets by `object`. In the end of each reduce() call, you know:

1. number of different `uid`s for object (number of received triplets)
2. total number of how much time `object` is owned (sum of `count` fields)

So, now you may apply both filters.

---

Single-job setup is also possible, but it requires manipulating with job on a bit lower level with [setSortComparatorClass()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setSortComparatorClass%28java.lang.Class%29), [setGroupingComparatorClass()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setGroupingComparatorClass%28java.lang.Class%29) and [setPartitionerClass()](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.6.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#setPartitionerClass%28java.lang.Class%29). Idea is that map() should emit composite keys which contain both `object` and `uid` fields, value is not used at all (NullWritable):

1. Partitioner class partitions keys only by using `object` field of the key. This guarantees that all records with the same `object` will go to the same reduce task.
2. SortComparator class is implemented in such way that first it compares `object` field, and if they are identical, `uid` field.
3. GroupingComparatorClass uses only `object` field for comparison.

In the result, input of single reduce task will look like following:

```
object1 uid1
object1 uid2
object1 uid2
object1 uid2
object1 uid5
object1 uid6
object1 uid6
------------  <- boundary of call to reduce
object7 uid1
object7 uid1
object7 uid5
------------- <-- boundary of call to reduce()
object9 uid3
```

As you can see, uids are strictly ordered inside each call to reduce(), which allows you to count both number of distinct and non-distinct uids simultaneously.